# Chrome extension google oauth 2 issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I have an issue with chrome extension and google oAuth 2.

I added all oAuth2 stuff in manifest.json.

Trying run this code in background.js

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true}, function (token) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }

    console.log(token);
});
```

Yesterday all was alright but today I got the error :

> OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'request
>   parameters violate OAuth2 client security restrictions'

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's problem but on other PCs all works. So, I checked it again on my work PC and now all work. I think the problem in chrome 'cause it's looks like chrome cached null value for token and just return an error.